# Plesk Laravel scheduler runs console app twice

Tags: php, laravel, plesk

I have added the Laravel scheduler as a scheduled task to Plesk see picture below

[image: Plesk scheduler]

I have added the following lines to app\Console\Kernel.php.

```
$schedule->command('*********')->dailyAt('06:00')->evenInMaintenanceMode()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping(10)->emailOutputTo('info@*****.com');
```

Everythings looks fine but the job is running twice, I get the following email notifications:

1. Scheduled Job Output For ['/usr/bin/php7.4' 'artisan' ***********]
2. Scheduled Job Output For ['/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php' 'artisan' ***********]

What have I done wrong?

**UPDATE** (copied from comments for readability)

Output of `crontab -l`:

```
MAILTO="" 
SHELL="/bin/bash" 
* * * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/*******.com/httpdocs && /opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And the same for root:
0 1 * * 1 /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/secur-check
0 1 * * 1 /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/send-report weekly
10 1 * * * /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/clean-sysstats
15 1 * * * /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/pack-sysstats day
15 1 * * 1 /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/pack-sysstats week
15 1 1 * * /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/pack-sysstats month
15 1 1 * * /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/pack-sysstats year
20 1 * * * /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/clean-events
0 3 * * 7 /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/clean-reports
47 23 * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate -b -s 2.pool.ntp.org

**UPDATE 2**
I did some more testing.
If I execute a function with $schedule->call() it is running once.

Comment: can you show us what `crontab -l` outputs?

Comment: Sure, that's:

MAILTO=""
SHELL="/bin/bash"
*       *       *       *       *       cd /var/www/vhosts/*******.com/httpdocs && /opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: and for root:

[root@server httpdocs]# crontab -l
watchdog jobs
0       3       *       *       7       /usr/local/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/clean-reports
47      23      *       *       *       /usr/sbin/ntpdate -b -s 2.pool.ntp.org

Comment: It is hard to read your cronjobs in unformatted comments. I added it to your question but the root output looks odd, can you pls edit and correct?  Also, have a look in  `/etc/cron.d/`, maybe a Laravel cronjob was added there at some point.

Comment: posted the full result in the original post

Comment: fixed an old cronjob was messing up